# django email fails to send in production, works for errors, fails for a particular view

Tags: django

I'm trying to automatically send an email with a django contact us form.

- The contact form view works in development properly via `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend`
- Sending of emails to admins for errors in procution works properly.

However sending emails for the contact view/form doesn't  work in production.

- No errors are produced in production when submitting the contact form.
- the post request appears in the logs, but there isn't any other useful information (that I can see) apart from that.

I'm not sure how best to pinpoint the error?

view:

```
@require_http_methods(['GET', 'HEAD', 'POST'])
def contact_view(request):
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = form.cleaned_data.get('contact_name', '')
            contact_email = form.cleaned_data.get('contact_email', '')
            email_content = form.cleaned_data.get('message', '')

            email = EmailMessage(
                subject="New contact form submission",
                body=email_content,
                to=('support@somedomain.com',),
                from_email=f'{contact_name} <{contact_email}>',
                reply_to=(contact_email,),
            )
            email.send()
            messages.success(request,
                             "Your email has been sent. Thanks for contacting us, we'll get back to you shortly")
            return redirect('contact')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'pages/contact.html', context)
```

production email settings:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = env('DJANGO_DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL',
                         default=' <noreply@some_domain.com>')
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = env('DJANGO_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX', default='[some_domain]')
SERVER_EMAIL = env('DJANGO_SERVER_EMAIL', default=DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL)

# Anymail with Mailgun
INSTALLED_APPS += ("anymail", )
ANYMAIL = {
    "MAILGUN_API_KEY": env('DJANGO_MAILGUN_API_KEY'),
    "MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN": env('MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN')
}
EMAIL_BACKEND = "anymail.backends.mailgun.EmailBackend"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your admin emails work because they are using `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` which is allowed.

Your email provider may not allow you to send emails from the address entered on the contact form.

You should use your email address for the `from_email`, and use the email address from the form as the `reply_to` email address.

Comment: Thanks that looked to be part of it, I've updated that view and pushed the change but didn't solve it. Contact form emails still aren't being sent out.  I'm not sure what else could be causing the issue? Is there a way to check if the django app is sending something out to the email provider (mailgun)

Comment: I don't have any specific tips for testing mailgun, but I would add as much logging to the method as possible, and perhaps write a minimal method that just sends an email so that you can narrow down where the problem is. Glad you figured out the problem in this case.